# What is the placeholder character in a kusto query language (KQL) matches statement?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to know what the placeholder character is in a contains statement in Kusto query language. In SQL I can have something similar to this:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'a__d%'
```

This will return the names starting with an 'a' and where the fourth character is the letter 'd'.
I need to do the same for a Kusto query. So I thought that I had to use the matches regex funtion in a way which is similar to somthing like this:

```
name matches regex "a.*d"
```

But this does not work the way I want it to. So, what is the equivalent of SQL's underscore character in KQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a regular expression that would match your requirement of *"starting with an 'a' and where the fourth character is the letter 'd'"* can be seen in the following example.

```
datatable(s:string)["axxxxd123","a1234d","adabc","b","a12345dsomething"]
| where s matches regex "^a.{4}d.*"
```

this will return the first 2 values: `axxxxd123` and `a1234d`

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I need :)